# How to add xml-stylesheet tags to an XML file using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I need to add the following code to the beginning of an XML file, while creating it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="colors.xslt"?>
```

I'm sure there is a method for this, but I haven't found it yet. I'm using C#.
Thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[XmlDocument.CreateProcessingInstruction Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createprocessinginstruction.aspx)

```
public static void Main()
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateProcessingInstruction(
        "xml-stylesheet", 
        "type='text/xsl' href='colors.xslt'"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For LINQ XDocument you can use this:

```
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
    xDoc.Add(new XProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", 
                                        "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"xml-style.xslt\""));
```